# In c++11 passing a lambda function to scandir is probably impossible. What's the next best thing?

Tags: c++11, lambda, scandir, instance-methods

I need an instance method or a lambda function or it's equivalent to be passed as the select function argument to scandir. Is there any way to do this?

The key thing I'm trying to achieve is to have the select function (the callback) see different parameters for each instance of the class which calls it. To make this thread-safe, or just not horribly ugly, I can't just store my parameters in a global variable, that's what class instances are for.

Here's what it would look like if it worked with lambda functions in c++11:

```
myclass:getFilesMatching(char startChar)
{
   ...
   mParam = startChar;
   auto lfunc = [this] (const struct dirent * dent) { return (*(dent->d_name) == mParam); };
   mNumFiles = scandir((char *)fullDirPath, &mfileList, lfunc, NULL);
}
```

This would get all files whose name starts with the specified character. I don't care if I pass in local variables or instance variables to the function.

I hope scandir is itself threadsafe. Of course I could use semaphores or a mutex, but is that really necessary?

Of course this is only a simple example of the select function. What I actually want to do is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I have no previous knowledge of the `scandir` or any of the related C functions. But from what I understand from reading through the documentation on the `<dirent.h>` it is a helper function that wraps multiple calls to lower level APIS.

In cases like these I prefer creating a C++ wrapper that implements the same functionality, with a C++ like API.

Starting with a wrapper around the `DIR` type to ensure that it is properly cleaned up:

```
namespace cpp {

    struct DIR { 
        ::DIR * dir;

        DIR(const std::string & path) : dir(opendir(path.c_str()))
        {
            if(dir==0) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open path");
        }

        ~DIR() { if(dir!=0) closedir(dir); } 

        operator ::DIR * () { return dir; }
    };
}
```

The `scandir` function can now be implemented something like this:

```
template<class Filter, class Compare>
std::vector<dirent> scandir(const std::string & path, const Filter& filter, const Compare& compare) {
    cpp::DIR dir(path);
    std::vector<dirent> res;
    dirent entry, *entry_ptr = &entry;
    while( ::readdir_r(dir, &entry, &entry_ptr)==0 ) {
        if( entry_ptr==0 ) break;
        if( filter(entry) ) res.push_back(entry);
    }

    std::sort(begin(res), end(res), compare);

    return res;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
std::string path = ...;
...
auto filter = [] (const dirent& entry) { return entry.d_name[0]!='.'; };
auto compare = [](const dirent & lhs, const dirent & rhs) {
    return std::strcmp(lhs.d_name, rhs.d_name)<0; 
};

auto entries = cpp::scandir(path, filter, compare);
```

The use of `readdir_r()` makes the implementation above thread-safe, although more checks should be added to report any errors returned by it.

NOTE: The code above requires the following headers to be included:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

```
void with_file_names(const std::string &path,
                     std::function<void(const std::string& name)> action,
                     int(*filter)(const struct dirent *) = NULL)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    auto nfiles = scandir(path.c_str(),
                          &namelist,
                          filter,
                          NULL);
    for (auto idx = 0; idx < nfiles; idx++) 
    {
        auto n = namelist[idx];
        action(std::string(n->d_name, n->d_namlen));
    }
    free(namelist);
}
```

and then

```
with_file_names("./downloaded",
                [](const std::string &file_name){
                    auto fullname = std::string("./downloaded/") + file_name;
                    // do something...
                },
                [](const struct dirent *pentry) {
                    return (int)(::strncmp("node-", pentry->d_name, 5) == 0);
                });
```

notice the filter parameter as a lambda. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, you can't pass arguments to the filter function using a lambda function, so this does not really help.

Comment: @Étienne it’s funny, because it _almost_ helps – he’s using non-capturing lambdas (which can actually be converted to function pointers and thus are theoretically valid operands for `scandir`) but the use of `std::function` as an interlocutor totally clobbers that possibility. Changing `std::function` to `std::add_pointer_t` (from `type_traits`) might actually work (I have gotten something similar to work with `scandir`).

Comment: I used it on modified versions of FileZilla so I can say it works as described.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to marry `scandir` with lambda expressions, with an interesting result: looks like there is a loophole (probably a version-and-compiler specific bug) that allows to generate a working executable file from the following code, with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

char *ext;
unsigned int lext;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dirent **listing;
    ext = argv[2];
    lext = strlen (ext);
    int n = scandir (argv[1],
                     &listing,
                     [ext , lext] (const struct dirent *ent) -> int
                     {
                        // Select only files with extension EXT
                        auto lon = strlen (ent->d_name);
                        return (lon > lext  and
                                 !strcmp (ent->d_name + (lon-lext), ext))
                            ? 1 : 0;
                     },
                     alphasort);
    if (n==-1)
    {
        cout << "scandir has failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "scandir has found "<< n <<" matching entries.\n";
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i)
            cout << i+1 << " - "<< listing[i]->d_name << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you try to correct the scoping of the capture list variables, making them block-local, it will refuse to compile with the following error:

> error: cannot convert ‘main(int, char**)::’ to ‘int (*)(const dirent*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int scandir(const char*, dirent***, int (*)(const dirent*), int (*)(const dirent**, const dirent**))’

This seems to mean that it is *possible* to compile a lambda into a function, so a pointer to it can be given to `scandir` in a way that works. However, I prefer the C++ approach of the other 2 answers.

I don't know if this should be considered a compiler bug.

Comment: Yeah – only non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers. So not a compiler bug; q.v. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda